# About Microsoft turning off IMAP protocol communication. When I use imaplib in python I get this error: b'LOGIN failed'

Tags: python, authentication, outlook, imaplib

My sample code block;

```
import imaplib

try:
    userName = "test@abc.com"
    passwd = "***"
    SMTP = "outlook.office365.com"
    Port = "993"
    imapSession = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SMTP, Port)
    imapSession.login(userName, passwd)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Return: error:  b'LOGIN failed.'

I'm sure my email and password are correct.
Microsoft Office 365 announced that it is shutting down imap protocol communications. How can I do my mail reading operations via office 365?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not shutting down IMAP4. They are disabling Basic Authentication - you need to use OAuth.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth